# Lightning application form, unable to submit because of SecureAction

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-community, lightning-namespace

I created a Lightning application with a form. When I hit submit in my form, nothing happens. I look in the browser console and see that I'm getting the following message:

```
SecureAction: [object Object]{ key: {"namespace":"c"} }
```

It appears to be happening when I reach this line in my Helper.js code:

```
var action = component.get("c.saveForm");
```

I've had my coworkers try and submit this application under their own logins, and they are all able to submit the application, only I am not able to and seeing the SecureAction message. We all have Salesforce admin accounts and from the looks of it, mine is setup the same. So I log into the sandbox using another coworkers account (who we've verified can submit a form) and I see the SecureAction message again.

I'm at a loss for what to do, any suggestions are welcome. Thanks.

Comment: Have you installed Lightning inspector chrome plugin? Have you enabled any critical update? . Can you post complete code, its hard to determine what could go wrong.

Comment: What exactly is happening? Is there an error message? can you verify that you have a controller method called `saveForm` and that you have marked the apex class that contains this method as the controller for this component and finally have you marked the method in the controller as `@AuraEnabled` ? Oh and make sure it's public static.

Comment: @PranayJaiswal genius! I installed the Lightning inspector chrome plugin and found I was getting some simple error that I never saw otherwise (INVALID_OR_NULL_FOR_RESTRICTED_PICKLIST). And the reason only I was having this issue and not my coworkers is because I told them they only  needed to fill out required fields (which this is not).

Comment: I am putting this as an answer, can you accept it, it will others with similar issue debug faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lightning chrome inspector plugin Decrypts the actual response. Installing/ activating plugin solves the issue and returns a proper response.

Comment: @Leela done for it :/